# in my morris.js graph the date on the X axis is adding the number 19 before the month-day date

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, morris.js

this is the sql to get the data from data base and puts the data in an array. also it splits the date from year-month-day format to month-day format

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Time WHERE Event_ID='$event' AND Student_ID='$runner'";
        $result=$conn->query($sql);     
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $date[]= date('m-d',strtotime($row['Date']));
            $time[]=$row['time'];
            $count=$count+1;
        }
```

this is the script that is used to create the graph.

```js
new Morris.Line({
  // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
  element: 'myfirstchart',
  // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
  // the chart.
  data: [     { day: '11-02', t:37},
      { day: '11-04', t:22},
    {day: '11-06', t: 83}
  ],
  // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
  xkey: 'day',
  // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
  ykeys: ['t'],
  // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
  // chart.
  labels: ['Time']
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
  
  
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:900px;">
   <h2 align="center">Morris.js chart with PHP & Mysql</h2>
   <h3 align="center">Last 10 Years Profit, Purchase and Sale Data</h3>   
   <br /><br />
   <div id="myfirstchart" style="height: 250px;"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The javascript code is hard to read with the php mixed in with it. Can you run this in a browser, view source, and then copy and paste the rendered javascript source so it won't have the php tags in it?

Comment: there you go ive updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the date in the x-axis without the year, you need to format it in javascript instead of in php. When you get a date like "11-05" from php, morris parses that back into a javascript date object, and it doesn't have the year part, so it ends up parsing the date as "May, 1911". Leave the formatting alone in php, and then set the formatting in morris with `xLabelFormat`, ie

```
 $date[] = $row['Date'];
```

and

```
  element: 'myfirstchart',
  xLabelFormat: function(date) { return (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate(); }
  data: [ //...
```

Snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>chart with PHP & Mysql | lisenme.com </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
  
 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:900px;">
   <h2 align="center">Morris.js chart with PHP & Mysql</h2>
   <h3 align="center">Last 10 Years Profit, Purchase and Sale Data</h3>   
   <br /><br />
   <div id="myfirstchart" style="height: 250px;"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
// this is the script that is used to create the graph.
<script>
new Morris.Line({
  // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
  element: 'myfirstchart',
  // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
  // the chart.
  xLabelFormat: function(date) { return (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate(); },
  data: [     { day: '2020-11-02', t:37},
      { day: '2020-11-04', t:22},
    {day: '2020-11-06', t: 83}
  ],
  // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
  xkey: 'day',
  // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
  ykeys: ['t'],
  // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
  // chart.
  labels: ['Time']
});
</script>
```